# Finding country from coordinates using Python

Tags: python, coordinates, convert, latitude-longitude, twitter

I have tweets with coordinates. I'm trying to bucket the tweets by country using the coordinate information. I know that I can achieve this using some hosted web services but all of these have API limits that I am sure to run into.

I started writing this code learning from another resource about osgeo library.

```py
import osgeo.ogr

shapefile = osgeo.ogr.Open("geodata/worldborders/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp")
layer = shapefile.GetLayer(0)

for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()):
    feature = layer.GetFeature(i)
    countryCode = feature.GetField("ISO3")
    countryName = feature.GetField("NAME")
    print countryCode, countryName

    geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
```

The geometry variable has a member function called Contains that can take another Geometry and check whether the other is contained inside itself.

I have a coordinate value from Twitter data in the following format: [45.29680725, -75.92681408]. However an example on osgeo showcases creation of a point like this:

```py
point = osgeo.ogr.Geometry(osgeo.ogr.wkbPoint)
point.SetPoint(0, 474595, 4429281)
```

How do I convert my coordinates into the above-required format? If I do manage to convert, is this the right approach to mapping twitter coordinates to countries?

Comment: Removed answer once you made edit since you prefer to work with shapefile rather than GeoJSON.

Comment: Could you paste the link to the GeoJSON resource you provided in the answer? I could explore loading that data using shapely and using http://streamhacker.com/2010/03/23/python-point-in-polygon-shapely/. Am I correct in saying that the coordinates in the data file your shared are in the same format as those from Twitter as I showed above?

Comment: https://github.com/che0/countries solves the problem. I am unable to add an answer as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Here is the link, for anyone else who may be interested: https://04478727369367745762.googlegroups.com/attach/cd1638345088524c/world-countries.json?part=4&view=1&vt=ANaJVrG6xdMZwsyNDil5_nKz2QXQBSvbI8BCjFKOseu0xJJv0NJWDtEcYtIJ-BajUBVycVuJH_jEp8duePNjl-QbdIvgvXEG2DxZii1Jr22rHvH2M0vXVYc  The coordinates are Lat/Lng.

Comment: I am getting the error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CountryChecker.

Comment: **Related :** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159074/given-the-lat-long-coordinates-how-can-we-find-out-the-city-country and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497728/get-country-from-latitude-longitude

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This achieves finding country given coordinates: https://github.com/che0/countries

It uses a shapefile containing world borders loaded using python bindings for gdal.

Example:

```py
 import countries

 cc = countries.CountryChecker('TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp')
 print cc.getCountry(countries.Point(49.7821, 3.5708)).iso
```

The world borders shapefile can be obtained from http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php.

Comment: I tried the code and obtained: `AttributeError: module 'countries' has no attribute 'CountryChecker'`

Answer (score 3):

Given that you only need to find what country the tweets are in I guess the [VMAP0 data](http://gis-lab.info/qa/vmap0-eng.html) is sufficient.

As for Python libraries I would recommend looking at Shapely, which supports the [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) library, a turorial on point-in-polygon can be found [here](http://streamhacker.com/2010/03/23/python-point-in-polygon-shapely/). As for reading in the country polygons from the vmap0-data (which i presume are polygons in shapefiles), you should look at [ogr](http://streamhacker.com/2010/03/23/python-point-in-polygon-shapely/).

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question. Can you check it out please?